# when a python function is decorated, in which scopes is that decoration visible?

Tags: python, python-import, python-decorators

For example... given

1. the environment (A) [in which a module (B) is loaded] provides a function, e.g., 'register'
2. module (C) [imported by (B)] provides a set of utilities to load/run other scripts/modules/etc
3. module (D) is one of those 'other scripts' - it invokes 'register()' in its main-line (outer-most) scope so
   as to communicate D's primary entry-point (the function that does/starts D's service/work) as well as other items (including, eg parameters and appropriate default values) - 
   and
4. module (B) provides a function (runScript(filename...)) which when invoked -

   - a) validates the request,
   - b) decorates 'register' such that when (D) is loaded and executed as part of the import/load, the invocation of 'register' is handled by the decorator, which captures the entry point to be invoked subsequently,
   - c)  invokes the utility procedure in C that handles the nuances of which import mechanisms are available, and which then

     - i)  loads the script (by importing it) [which should exec the script, which should exec the function call to register, which should invoke the decorator, which should capture and save the 'registered' entry-point], and then
     - ii) retrieves and invokes the saved 'registered' entry-point

Neither (A) nor (D) may be modified - we can only modify code in B and/or C.

It appears that when B.runScript(filename) is invoked everything works as expected EXCEPT the wrapper.  The script does get loaded [ie if it had a Do method, it will be invoked. *1]
But if there is no Do method, registration did not capture the entry point.

I apologise in advance for my mis-understandings and/or misinterpretation/implementation

Module B (runScript - runScript.py):

```
import os
import App
def getEntryPoint(pi_registration):
    def registration(*args, **kwargs):
          App.plugin_EntryPoint = args[10]
          return True
    return registration

def runScript(filename):
    global register
    try:
        os.stat(filename)
        register = getEntryPoint(register)  # apply decorator
        App.Do("RunScript", { 'FileName' : filename })
    except:
        print "script inaccessible ("+filename+")"
```

Module C (App (Control/Emulation...) App.py):

```
import sys
import os
import path
import gimp
# etc...
plugin_EntryPoint = None

def Do(procedureName, options)
    # ...
    if procedureName == 'RunScript':
        filename = options['FileName'}
        # determine import mechanisms available --
        isimport = False
        isimportSFL = False
        isimportUtil = False
        isimportable = False
        try:
            import imp
            isimport = True
        except:
            pass
        if not isimport:
            # try alternative version's loader mechanism versions...
            try:
                from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
                isimportSFL = True

            except: 
                pass
            if not isimportSFL:
                try:
                    import importlib.util
                    isimportUtil = True
                except:
                    pass

        plugin_EntryPoint = None
        if isimport:
            moduleD = imp.load_source("module_D", filename)
        elif isimportSFL:
            moduleD = SourceFileLoader("module_D", filename)
        elif isimportUtil:
            modspec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module_D", filename)
            moduleD = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            spec.loader.exec_module(moduleD)

        if hasattr(moduleD, 'Do')
            moduleD.Do()                    # try conventional entry point...
        elif plugin_EntryPoint is None:     # try 'registered' entry point...
            raise AppTerminate, "no entry point registered"
        else
            pluginEntryPoint(App.plugin_Args)
    # ...
```

Module D (Service plug-in 'moduleD.py'):

```
def myEntrypoint():
    print "entered"

register("myName", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", [], [], myEntrypoint)

if __name__ == '__main__":
    main()
```

Environment (A):
Frankly, because I can not see *exactly* how the environment (gimpfu) sets this up, I can only surmise a *possible* equivalence for the question at hand:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def register(name, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, entrypoint):
     print "Plugin "+name+ " Entrypoint "+str(entrypoint)

import RunScript
RunScript._runScript("moduleD")
import _RunScript
```

Comment: I admit I did not read the whole question, but there are no decorated functions in that code... Maybe you are mistaking the meaning of "decorated"?

Comment: I think the decoration: `register = getEntryPoint(register)` only applies to module B. The `register` variable  is *global*, but only in module B. If another module loads D, it will see the original. You are probably after patching.

Comment: That is not really how decorators in python are supposed to be used... Decorators are used via a `@my_decorator`. Though technically you are doing a decorator...

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: but this *is* how decorators actually work under the covers.

Comment: @quamrana Very true. My reply was more to zvone while also making a generalization that this isn't the normal way you write a python decorator.

Comment: re @decoration syntax -- this is an (somewhat) recent addition in the long-term scheme of things - it was arrived at after a lot of discussion in the community -- the above actual does apply a decorator, just in the old-fashioned way

Comment: Can you derive a minimal working example @ChrysG? I think the answer is easy but it's hard to get over the word wall (and even harder to test anything since your code isn't runnable).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse:  I've tried to knock this down from a rather large set already.  Other than the #-- try other import mechanism-- just change the elif to if..  I will update the body of this to add that.  I cant shorten ModuleC any, its all needed to get to the problem..  Sorry about the word-wall -- as they said in school, ' a difficult problem is, er, difficult'. Give me a few moments to post an edit. Thx-1138

Comment: In `Do`  I only see `plugin_EntryPoint = None` and no other assignments yet there is a logic path that leads to `pluginEntryPoint(App.plugin_Args)` was *something else* supposed to have been assigned to `pluginEntryPoint`?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: I have tried to update the code snippets.

Comment: @wwii: What is supposed to happen is the following --

Comment: Where will `plugin_EntryPoint` not become `None`? Is there a `global plugin_EntryPoint ` somewhere in the code not pasted?

Comment: Do you have the full code it a git that we can see? Even if we can't run it in may be useful to see it all.

Comment: Before you do `global register` can you do a `print(globals(), locals(), dir())` and paste that. This will show you if a `register` exists in the global scope to use.

Comment: @wwii: What is supposed to happen is the following -- when moduleD is loaded it is executed (either by imp.load_source, by importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader or by the module spec loader (latest v of Python) as applicable to the version of Python available),  When executed during load it it invokes register().  The decorator is intended to intervene, capturing the entrypoint supplied and saving it in App.plugin_EntryPoint overriding the assignment to None (and thereby indicating that registration did work).  I eleted the code that scrubs the arguments to the plugin - I add if desired. CG

Comment: @ChrysG I don't think `global register` is doing what you want. `global` doesn't work properly in different files (this is why you should use classes), globals are usually a really bad idea. In essence [this is what is happening](https://repl.it/@Syntactical01/OutgoingTechnicalTitles). Note mine throws an error because I try to print instead of assign. You assign to a `global register` but that `register` is still only in the global scope of that file.

Comment: As you mention in your question, function decoration is nothing else than assigning a name to an object, e.g. when you do `func = decorator(func)` then code using this scope's `func` name will use the decorated function. It's easier to imagine when you use a different name: `func_decorated = decorator(func)`. All code that has access to `func_decorated` will use the decorated version and all code that has access to `func` will use the undecorated version. The only difference with `func = decorator(func)` is that is might override the name `func`. Using different names you can trace it down.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: I posted the code in its unvarnished state at chrysalis-systems_dot_net _slash_ appDo  .. The .register file is the registration part of moduleD plugin

Comment: @a_guest: so the question is: how do we apply a 'wrapper' that can be visible to functions invoked _by_ the current function/module/etc?

Comment: @ChrysG I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which covers just that part? I mean if you do `func = decorator(func)` and then later, in the same scope, `func()` then it's obviously the decorated version. As mentioned, function decoration basically assigns a name to an object, and the visibility of that name has nothing to do with function decoration. It seems your questions is about assignment and scopes in general rather than function decoration.

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately devolves to the static versus dynamic scope question for Python -- Hence, the functions' scopes are static and only visible with in the module and not any module that it itself might import.

Commentary:  Aw, shucks.  I guess after doing a lot of systems programming work where we 'slip' a layer into a functional stack, (intercepting service requests for the lower layer without affecting layers above it in the stack (making the service requests), I was hoping that there would be a way, some way, to accomplish the same. [c'est la guerre]